# Export Random Password - Import and reset user password

Tags: powershell, import, passwords, export

Is it possible to import a randomly generated password and set it to a users account?

The below only brings back the following:

> Cannot convert the "Password" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

---

```
$testing1 = read-host "Enter name"
$usertesting = Get-Aduser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$testing1'" 

$fileNameDate = Get-Date
$fileNameDate = $fileNameDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss')

$Password = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$Password | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Password" -Value { ("!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".tochararray() | sort {Get-Random})[0..12] -join '' }
$Password | Export-csv -Path "C:\Output\$fileNameDate.txt" -notypeinformation

$passwordImport = import-csv "C:\Output\$fileNameDate.txt" | ForEach-Object { Set-ADAccountPassword -identity $testing1 -NewPassword $_.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force }
```

Comment: You need to either create the SecureString previously in your script or enclose it in brackets: `-NewPassword ($_.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)`.  Also, I'm not sure what the CSV file is adding to your code (except additional complication).

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you save the password (as a csv) and read it back before converting it to a secure string?

Try this (untested)

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\30\SO_53064023.ps1

$testing1 = read-host "Enter name"
$usertesting = Get-Aduser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$testing1'" 

$filenamedate = "C:\Output\{0}.txt" -f (get-date -f 'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss')

$PassWord = -join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" |Get-Random -Count 13)
$Password | Export-csv -Path $fileNameDate -NoTypeInformation

$SecPW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PassWord -AsPlainText -Force

Set-ADAccountPassword -identity $testing1 -NewPassword $SecPW
```

Comment: Setting an account to a random pass will be ok but we won't know it. It's part of some automation testing.